# I need to create one menu from home page and the other menu for other pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to use a menu in home and another menu in the other page so I use this code (in page-header.php):

```
<?php if(!is_single()) :?>      
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Menu1' )) ; >
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if(is_single()) :? >
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Menu2' )); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it doesn't work. Anyone can help me?

Comment: where is code placed? header.php? reason i am asking is because that method does work in post types attachments and pages

Comment: Have you tried either of the menus outside of an if statement? One of those statements will always be true. Also you can replace `<?php endif; ?><?php if(is_single()) :? >` with `<?php else: ?>` - same thing in your case.

Answer (score 0):

the right method for the job is `is_singular()` because this will make sure the page you are looking at is actually a single page. also no need to for having two if statement, is either true or false.

```
<?php if(is_singular()) :?>      
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Menu1' )) ; >
<?php else: ?>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Menu2' )); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: @poopp like I said in the comment where is this piece of code placed? template? header? sidebar?

Comment: page-header.php

Comment: sorry the page is header-default.php